# How to open a file uploaded by a user in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

So I am attempting to open and manipulate user uploaded files that have been stored in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory of my Django app.

As of right now I can only open files that are in my project directory. My attempts to access the files in my `Data_Files` directory that is within my `media` directory are as follows:

## Attempt #1

```
file_upload_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Data_Files')
data_file = open(os.path.join(file_upload_dir, new_file), 'rb')
raw_data = data_file.read()
```

## Attempt #2

```
file_upload_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Data_Files')
data_file = default_storage.open(os.path.join(file_upload_dir, new_file), 'r')
raw_data = data_file.read()
```

My second attempt leverages Django's `FileStorage API` but neither are allowing me to access files anywhere besides the files within the project directory.

The error given is:

```
file b'PVP3.CSV' does not exist
```

with a traceback of:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphite/file_upload/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'graphite',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.7.1-py3.4.egg\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\vut46744\Desktop\graphite_project\graphite\views.py" in upload_file
  112.  data_df = html_graph(request)
File "C:\Users\vut46744\Desktop\graphite_project\graphite\views.py" in html_graph
  310.      data_df = pd.read_csv(new_file, skiprows=header_row).drop(0, axis=0).astype(float)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in parser_f
  465.         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in _read
  241.     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in __init__
  557.         self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in _make_engine
  694.             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py" in __init__
  1056.         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

Exception Type: OSError at /graphite/file_upload/
Exception Value: File b'PVP3.CSV' does not exist
```

Is there a different way to access those files, or is there something logically wrong with my code?

Comment: You haven't said what goes wrong when you try either of these.

Comment: Ah I meant to add the error/Traceback but forgot. See edit.

Comment: Did you check if the file is actually there? Also try and print the absolute path of the place you're trying to open the file at and see if it's sane. You shouldn't be doing this stuff as part of a blocking web request by the way, but I don't know if you are.

Comment: @BjornTipling The file does exist, but perhaps the problem is that I am presenting a graph to the user that is generated from data within the file and in the graph view it is trying to reference the file before it is saved in the `media` directory?

Comment: Have you tried using pdb? You could verify this.

Comment: @BjornTipling I'm using `debug_toolbar` and it verifies that the file is inserted into the database and in the `media` directory.

Comment: If you use pdb.set_trace() you could verify the timing of these actions.

Comment: @BjornTipling Well I actually just removed the graph and accompanying HTML table that leverages the data within the file and it still was unable to locate the file so unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue.